# How do I resolve "Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered" - After expo eject - React-Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

After I did 'expo-eject' to my project,

When I try to use this command: " react-native run-android "

This is what i get :

[image]

node.js version: v12.18.0

React-Native version: 

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.61.5

**And this is my 'package.json' file:**

{
  "scripts": {

    "start": "react-native start",

    "android": "react-native run-android",

    "ios": "react-native run-ios",

    "web": "expo start --web"

  },

  "dependencies": {

    "expo": "^37.0.6",

    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.2.3",

    "expo-updates": "~0.2.0",

    "react": "~16.9.0",

    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",

    "react-native": "~0.61.5",

    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",

    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",

    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",

    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.9.0",

    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",

    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",

    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.4.1",

    "expo-location": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~8.1.0",

    "font": "0.0.4",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.7.9",

    "react-native-navigation-apps": "^1.0.27",

    "react-native-paper": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.7",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.11",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^3.0.5",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.2.10",

    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.11",

    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.11",

    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",

    "redux": "^4.0.5"

  },

  "devDependencies": {

    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",

    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",

    "jest": "~25.2.6",

    "react-test-renderer": "~16.9.0",

    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"

  },

  "private": true

}